# basic types in C

Tags: c, types

So quick, odd question:
I took an exam, and a question was:

```
char c = 'A'
char *p =&c
char **p2 = &p
void *v = &p2
```

Write the type (i.e. int, void*, etc.) of the following expression:

1. `&v`
2. `p2 + 1`
3. `v[0]`

I answered:

1. `void **`
2. `char**`
3. ILLEGAL

and lost full credit. I just wanted to get a second opinion from someone before I try to get points back.

1. I wasn't too sure about, but I figured that, since `v` was a `void` pointer to a memory address, the address of `v` would have been a `void**`. If `v` was dereferenced, however, it would be a `char****`.
2. `p2` is a `char**`, so adding 1 to it would still make it a `char**`.
3. `v[0]` doesn't exist.

If someone could help me out with this kind of dumb problem, I'd be very grateful.
Thank you.

Comment: `v` cannot be dereferenced by itself (i.e. without a cast). This makes the last sentence of your first point wrong but your third answer correct.

Comment: Guess you mean something like "if v was casted to the type that can be dereferenced to get the value of c" instead of "if v was dereferenced"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answers are correct, for the reasons you gave (apart for the bit about dereferencing `v`, although it sounds like you already know that you can't dereference a `void *`).

Comment: what does 'you cannot dereference a `void *`' mean? A potential compile-time/runtime error? Just thought you can do it, but you get a meaningless data. Could you please explain further. It is also a point I'm not sure:). Thanks.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea: The compiler will not allow you to do: `void *v; ... *v;`.  It simply won't compile.

Comment: I tried on my box. `v[0]` indeed has a size, the `sizeof(v[0])` is 1. But an error thrown when I want to get `v[0]`. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

`p2+1` is a segfault waiting to happen, and `v[0] == *(v+0) == *v` which is void and therefore invalid. It should be a char** if typecasted.